# Flutter Differentiate between devices via unique ID / IMEI / Serialnumber?

Tags: android, flutter, uid, serial-number

I wanted to know if there is a prefered way to fetch a unique "ID" from the user of the app.
The thing is that I need to differentiate between phones under one "Company Account".

As it seems, android and apple made it hard for us to get the needed information.

The best shot seems to be:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_udid

But I just want to know if there is a better solution?

flutter_udid looks good, but I am a bit surprised that Android/Apple are giving us a hard time fetching a unique device UID

Comment: Couple of months ago , i tested the packages in the answers , and they are not working as expected , and change when app is closed (may be they fix it now but idk)
my suggestion : if you are concerned about IOS only , search for a device_token in native and pass it through method channel in flutter, for both platforms my recommendation is to identify each one by saving a key in their local storage, one side down is that it will be prune when un-installing the app , however you can add an algorithm or so to check which device was that

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to get device id.
This id is unique and does not change until the device is reset. You can use it for identification.

> platform_device_id: ^1.0.1

Add `platform_device_id` to your `pubspec.yaml`.

Here's code to get device Id using `platform_device_id` package.

```
import 'package:platform_device_id/platform_device_id.dart';

String? deviceId = await PlatformDeviceId.getDeviceId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [device_info_plus](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_info_plus) plugin developed by Flutter community. This is how you can get IDs on both platform.

In your `pubspec.yaml` file add this:

```
dependencies:
  device_info_plus: ^3.2.3
```

Create a method:

```dart
Future<String?> _getId() async {
  var deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  if (Platform.isIOS) { // import 'dart:io'
    var iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    return iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor; // unique ID on iOS
  } else if(Platform.isAndroid) {
    var androidDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
    return androidDeviceInfo.androidId; // unique ID on Android
  }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
String? deviceId = await _getId();
```